# How to access cookies when using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, cookies, browser

I have some cookies stored in a cookie container in which I obtained using HttpWebRequest.  I then proceeded to place those cookies into the WebBrowser object and do a navigate with the following code:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

for (int i = 0; i < webProcCookies.Count; i++)
{
    Cookie c = webProcCookies[i];

    InternetSetCookie(URL, c.Name, c.Value); 
}

wb.Navigate(URL, "_self", null, "User-Agent: XXX");
```

Now when I run this through fiddler I can see ALL the cookie data.  When I step through this with the debugger the cookie is only displaying a little bit of data.  I want to be able to access the entire cookie data during runtime.

Is there anyway to access ALL values of the cookie before I do Navigate?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

To get all cookies use  Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

Something like

```
string[] webProcCookies= Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
foreach (string cookie in webProcCookies)
{
  //Your Code
}
```